# Is there a shortcut to run `flutter pub get` in Android Studio?

Tags: git, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-dependencies

Sometimes when I switch branches, the IDE shows errors in Dart files. In Android or iOS dev, I'd do a clean and rebuild. Or a "gradle sync".

I've found that the closest equivalents are `flutter doctor` and `flutter pub get`. In my issue mentioned above, `flutter pub get` fixes it and runs quickly.

**Is there a shortcut or button to quickly run this from Android Studio?** I know I can type it into terminal, but would love a shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a few options! Sadly there is no button and I haven't found a plugin that adds one. But I've found the next closest thing.

##### Option 1 (action search)

1. Run the "Search Everywhere" command (which searches actions). For me, it is **double shift**.
2. Type "pub get" and press enter

This will run the command found in `Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Pub Get`

##### Option 2 (shortcut)

Using the same option above, you can use a keymap.

1. Go to Settings (`cmd + ,`) -> Keymap
2. Search for "pub get"
3. Bind it to whatever you want (I did `ctrl + b`)

##### Option 3 (Flutter Enhancement)

Using the Android Studio plugin [Flutter Enhancement Suite](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12693-flutter-enhancement-suite).

1. Download Flutter Enhancement Suite
2. Right-click the lib directory and select "Run Pub Get"